# gulp_jspm Domain property building project using gulp

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, gulp, jspm

I am getting this error when I try build my project using gulp. It is getting trigger with this logic gulp_jspm. Is there something else I should use to create my bundle files? Do I use this gulp-jspm-builder?

```
[11:18:42] Starting 'bundle:template'...
(node:31888) [DEP0097] DeprecationWarning: Using a domain property in MakeCallback is deprecated. Use the async_context variant of MakeCallback or the AsyncResource class instead. (Triggered by calling processImmediate on process.)
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[11:18:42] 'bundle:template' errored after 57 ms


var createBundleTask = function (entryPoint, packageId) {
    if (typeof entryPoint === "undefined") {
        throw "ArgumentNullException: entryPoint";
    }

    if (typeof packageId === "undefined") {
        throw "ArgumentNullException: packageId";
    }

    var task = gulp.src(entryPoint)
        .pipe(gulp_jspm({
            selfExecutingBundle: true
        }),true)
        .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/bundle"))
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); });
    return task;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011636/how-to-resolve-using-a-domain-property-in-makecallback-is-deprecated-warning-w

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58784689/node-error-using-a-domain-property-in-makecallback-is-deprecated

Comment: Have you tried using this options `--trace-deprecation`?

Comment: Is that option in gulp?

Comment: This isn't an issue with `gulp`, one of your modules (I'm guessing `gulp_jspm`) must be importing the [domain](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/domain.html) module, which is deprecated. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786020/864233

Comment: when I remove this line it works fine `.pipe(gulp_jspm({`>

Comment: @romellem do i use some other tool that will replace gulp_jspm?

Comment: Do you have to use `gulp_jspm`? And are you sure you installed this module correctly?

Comment: Yes I need to use it to buld the bundle.js file.